# Is there a sign for "according to?"

Tags: notation, terminology, article-writing

There are signs in mathematics for "therefore" and "because," which are $\therefore$ and $\because$ respectively.

However, another frequently-used expression is "according to." Is there any symbol for that?

Comment: Do you mean it like "according to [reference]" or "according to Eq. (X)", or something mathematical? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Lovsovs I mean both, as a matter of fact. I would have thought that it would be the same, but even if it isn't I'd like to know, as I haven't come across anything like it before.

Comment: Sometimes the clearest  route is simply using "according to...".  Clarity isn't guaranteed by finding symbolic notation for every notion. When meaning is dependent on context (according to Plato...), according to figure 1.a..., etc

Comment: @amWhy thank you. I understand that, but I'm asking because I write it a lot for school/for homework and would rather not waste time writing it out. However, in writing papers, I'll make sure to keep that in mind.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use some actual words.

Comment: Instead of "according to Eq. $(3)$", you can also often write "by Eq. $(3)$". Less typing, and using both gives additional variation of formulation.

Comment: @DanielFischer that is a very useful tip. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: @SkeletonBow: I would be surprised if finding out an obscure notation (and explaining it to everyone to whom you write) for it was more cost-effective by any reasonable metric than actually spelling out the words.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there isn't, and it isn't good practice to use mathematical/formalistic symbols in the middle of a sentence.

For instance:

"Now, Eq. (1) $\rightarrow$ that Eq. (2) is $\sim$ true,"

instead of

"Now, Eq. (1) implies that Eq. (2) is false,"

only makes the sentence more obscure. You could write out every sentence as a logical statement, but ask yourself, "what text would I rather read?" Your audience probably would choose the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On a side note, should I use a single or a double arrow for "implies that?"

Comment: @SkeletonBow Single; the double is a "double implication," which has a different (stronger) meaning.

Comment: @Lovsovs OP means "$\implies$" versus "$\to$", perhaps.

Comment: @Lovsovs What’s the meaning of the double implication? Oh, you mean the equivalence arrow “⇔”, right?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff you're correct, my bad. I assumed "double arrow" was synonymous with "double striped arrow."

Comment: @k.stm Yes, "iff".

Comment: @SkeletonBow They often mean the same, but when doing some algebraic manipulations, I'd actually stick to using $\implies$. $\rightarrow$ can also be used, but is also used when defining functions ($f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$). See [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) for more details.

Comment: @Lovsovs thank you very much for the detailed, informative reply!

Comment: I've never seen $\sim$ used as a mathematical notation for logical negation...

Comment: @Rhymoid Look at the wiki-link I posted in the answer (search for "not").

Comment: To be fair, you deliberately constructed this example to be hard to read. I see nothing wrong with "Now, Eq. (1) $\Rightarrow \neg$ Eq. (2)". In fact, I find this easier to read at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Latin abbreviation *sec.* from *secundum*, meaning "following" or "in accordance with", sometimes used as "sec. Smith", which means "according to Smith".

Comment: Interesting! Would it be applicable for something like sec. Eq (1) or sec. [reference to rule]?

Comment: @SkeletonBow I have no idea! If not for my exceptional google-fu, I wouldn't even know about this abbreviation. ;)

Comment: @SkeletonBow : You should only use this abbreviation if you do not want people to know what you mean.